# Javascript regex issue with strings containing UTF-8 characters

Tags: javascript, regex, utf-8

For some reason `/(d+)/` (checks if there are any digits in the string) doesn't work if the string contains any UTF8 characters.

```
text = "ребёнок от 5 до 10 лет"
text.match(/(d+)/) >> null

text = "child 5 to 10 years"
text.match(/(d+)/) >> != null
```

There should be a fairly easy solution to this.

Comment: did you actually see the result of the last one ? it returns `["d","d"]`

Comment: I'll just point out that `A` is a UTF-8 character. So is `q`. And a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add `\` to get `\d`, a digit shorthand class:

```js
text = "ребёнок от 5 до 10 лет";
alert(text.match(/(\d+)/));
```